# Scala create a numeric from a string

Tags: scala

I want to do something like this:

```
def parse[A: Numeric](str: String): A = {
   if A =:= Int, str.toInt
   if A =:= Float, str.toFloat
   if A =:= BigInt, BigInt(str)
   ...
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no `fromString` defined in the `Numeric` trait. What is the most idiomatic way to achieve this in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is in general impossible by the extendable nature of typeclasses; there is no way you could match against all possible implementations of `Numeric` because any user-defined type could implement it. Likewise because of that, it's not guaranteed that every `Numeric[A]` is parseable from a string.

There's two ways out of this. One is a partial solution where you make sure you only use strings representing integer literals, then use `Int`'s `fromString` to parse it and `Numeric`'s `fromInt` to convert it.

The other way is to pass in the actual string parsing function when the function is called. This can kind of feel like cheating as your `parse` method no longer does any real work, but can be made to be quite useful with implicits.

The most straightforward way is to just add a (maybe implicit) `String -> A` parameter (or maybe `String -> Option[A]` for fewer runtime errors). Another way of achieving this is to go the [the typeclass route again and implement something like a `Readable` typeclass](http://www.smartjava.org/content/scala-typeclass-explained-implement-stringread-function). Then you can have your function be the following:

```
def parse[A: Numeric: Readable](x: String): A = ...
```

Now you just need to make sure you have `Readable[A]` implementations for all the `A` you care about.

Comment: That's exactly what I do here (see the `Scannable` type class): https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/better/files/Scanner.scala#L79-L86  But I wish Scala's Numeric trait had a `fromString` in it...

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, I think there's a better way. Let me write up the edit....

Comment: Never mind; everything I can think just devolves back into the same thing. The only other thing I could think of was perhaps using `spire` and using its `Integral` typeclass and then matching on whether it's a `Fractional` or just an `Integral` and then using the respective `fromDouble` or `fromInt` methods (together with `toDouble` and `toInt`) to parse it. Your `Scannable` seems fine, but I wouldn't call myself a Scala expert and would defer to others.

Comment: I opened a Scala minor issue for this: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9706. This would even simplify Scala's internal `.toByte`, `.toInt` code too...

Comment: I'll be interested to see where that goes. FWIW, I'm of the opinion that actually a general `Readable` typeclass in the standard library is the way to go and that adding parsing to the responsibility of the typeclass conflates what should be separate concerns. I'll reserve judgment though and see what the core Scala team thinks.

Comment: Makes sense. `Read` is missing from both cats and Scalaz: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Read.html too.